# Can you explain 2:223

Tags: quran, women

> Your wives are like farmland for you,1 so approach them ˹consensually˺ as you please.2 And send forth something good for yourselves.3 Be mindful of Allah, and know that you will meet Him. And give good news to the believers.
> Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran **2:223**

Some people say this verse mean that women are farmland and they should be treated as a baby making factory.
Mostly non muslim say this.

But can you explain this why Allah reaveld this verse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

① As per tafsir, the verse was revealed to let Muslims know that you can be intimate with your spouse in any position, refuting the 'People of the Book' [Jews specifically] who were claiming that entering from the back would cause harm to the baby. Islam was correct.

② The 'farmland' (tilth) metaphor is just pointing out that it is through women that men have offspring, which is just a fact of life. From Tafsir Ibn Kathir: "*Ibn `Abbas commented, "Meaning the place of pregnancy*." There is nothing wrong with pointing this out. Women should not be ashamed of how they are created nor should anti-Islam critics try to shame them on their ability to bear children nor should they shame men who want to have multiple children.

③ If non-Muslims want to know how Islam truly says to treat women, then they should know that Allah (ﷻ) said وعاشروهن بالمعروف [And live with them in kindness] - Qur'an 4:19. If interested, I wrote this article "[The Object Allegation](https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2018/01/27/the-object-allegation/)" to demonstrate that it's the world that treats women like objects [machines], not Islam.

I hope this helps.

Comment: For the sake of avoiding any confusion to the reader, I think it is extremely important here to mention that "entering from the back" here does not refer to anal sex. Anal sex is completely haraam.